# Как с помощью linux (или FreeDOS) настроить современный BIOS (UEFI)?

Tags: linux, администрирование, bios, uefi

Сначала немного фактов:

1. В современных `BIOS` есть функция сохранения настроек в виде файла на флэшку.
2. Ещё есть `EFI Shell`, который вроде бы как умеет работать из под `FreeDOS` (могу ошибаться). В самом БИОС точно можно вызвать отдельно.
3. Обновлялки от того же Asus работают на `FreeDOS`.
4. Есть [кроссплатформенный](https://www.flashrom.org/Downloads) проект [Flashrom](http://www.flashrom.org), который поддерживает кучу чипов для прошивки.
5. Linux [умеет](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=43795) писать в `UEFI`.
6. Есть технология [Intel AMT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Management_Technology), которая вообще может делать всё, что угодно и есть официальный [SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/amt-sdk/download).

**Собственно вопрос**: можно ли это как-то всё увязать? С обновлением проблем не возникает: Gigabyte и Asus кладут вместе с ROM-файлом прошивальщик нужной версии и даже `autoexec.bat`. А вот как потом воткнуть настройки (включить VT-x, выбрать First Boot Device, настроить WoL) пока не нашёл.

**Идеальный вариант решения**: За одну перезагрузку обновить БИОС и сразу же скормить файл настроек.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, ни bios, ни efi не позволяют перепрошить себя неродными утилитами.

Comment: @Ancient, 4-й и 5-й пункты читал?